# OpenGL functions not available in XCode 4.6

Tags: xcode, opengl

I have recently updated my XCode to version 4.6.1 Now when I am trying to run an OpenGL project it gives compilation errors for every OpenGL function I have used like "Use of undeclared identifier GL_PROJECTION" and "Use of undeclared identifier glLoadIdentity()" It is doing that for every gl function. I have created a new project on XCode 4.6.1, added OpenGL.framework, included the header file OpenGL/OpenGL.h

I opened the OpenGL/OpenGL.h header file and to my surprise, none of the OpenGL functions were present in it. There were a bunch of CGL functions. If so, then where are the OpenGL functions?

Another weird thing I just discovered is that I am able to use OpenGL functions in a .mm file but not in a .hpp file (I am using templates so I have created hpp file)

Could anyone let me know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to OSX development! I sold my Macbook Pro because of that kind of issue ;) (and of gdb asking me root password to start, what the…)

Comment: lol I know...I think I should sell mine too ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried `<OpenGL/gl.h>`?